# Get Image back from CGBitmapContextGetData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

So I have a `CGBitmapContext` and I get the pixel at a touchlocation using this

```
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (offscreenBuffer);

if (data != NULL) {
    offset = 4*((self.bounds.size.width*round(coord.y))+round(coord.x));
    int alpha =  data[offset];
    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];

}
```

And then I change the pixel colour like below.

```
data[offset]=255;
data[offset+1]=255;
data[offset+2]=0;
data[offset+3]=0;
```

My question is how do a get a CGImage back from the modified pixels so that I can update my `CGBitmapContext`?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2004/Nov/msg00024.html

Comment: I have already created a `CGBitmapContext` (offscreenBuffer) from which I gather the pixel data from. Are you suggesting I would need to create another with the new pixel arrangment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()` to generate a new `CGImage` from your context after modifying the data.

---

Changes you make to the data returned by `CGBitmapContextGetData()` should modify the context itself. That's a writable pointer, not a copy.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the step in between, applying the modified pixels to the `CGBitmapContext`

Comment: Thanks very much, I was treating it as a copy.